# How to show image inside a button?

Tags: css

How can I make the image inside the button fit better and higher quality?

```
<BUTTON onClick="ClipBoard(z#emp_ext#);"> <img src="copy-icon.png" style="height:16px;width:16px;"> </BUTTON>
```

Im using the image https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/174935/copy_icon .
Here is how it looks like with the code above.

I made a http://jsfiddle.net/e58s7jpy/ but don't show image here.
I wish i could post a image but need 10 reputation ;(.

Comment: Protip: uppercase tag names went out of fashion about 13 years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to save the image with btter quality by enhancing the pixels in the path which you refer.

Hope this helps. If happy, vote the answer.

> ```
> button div{
>     width:16px;
>     height:16px;
>     background-image: url(images/ui-icons_d19405_256x240.png);      
> }
> ```

you can also slightly enhance by Background modification and padding.